# PHP rename file on same host

Tags: php, file, rename

```
$url = 'http://site.com/images/name.jpg';
```

Its a full path for the file, which is already exists on ftp.

**How can I change file's name?**

Comment: If on the same server, you don't rename files based on their public URLs; you rename them based on their paths within your server's file system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others already point out, the PHP function you're looking for is [`rename`](http://www.php.net/rename), but you can't rename a file through a `http://` URL (At least not in PHP - As @Artefacto says, WebDAV can do this.).

You will need to specify a proper filesystem path.

Answer (score 5):

if your script on the server root (`http://site.com/script.php`) that script will do:

```
rename('images/oldname.jpg', 'images/newname.jpg');
```

since that's the relative path of the image from the script point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `rename()` function.  Seems to be what you're looking for here.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php